# Comparing Using 2 Properties in Ascending and Descending Orders

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I have an object that has multiple properties, two of which the user can choose to order by, both can be Ascending, Descending, or neither (Normal), and they are independent of each other. So my cases are:

**Case 1**

- propA - Normal
- propB - Normal

**Case 2**

- propA - Asc
- propB - Normal

**Case 3**

- propA - Desc
- propB - Normal

And you get the idea. I'm using a `Comparator` to do this, and so far I have been able to get it to sort when one or both values are set to `Normal`. The part that I'm unsure of is what to do when I have chosen to sort by both methods. For example, if I want to order by propA ascending and propB descending, it should look a little like this

```
propA    propB
  A        Z
  A        D
  B        M
  B        A
  R        Q
  Z        Z
  Z        A
```

Here is how I'm sorting now

```
@Override
public int compare(Field lhs, Field rhs) {
    switch (growerSort) {
        case NORMAL:
            switch (fieldSort) {
                case NORMAL:
                    return ((Integer) lhs.getID()).compareTo(rhs.getID());
                case ASC:
                    return lhs.getPropB().toLowerCase().compareTo(rhs.getPropB().toLowerCase());
                default:
                    return rhs.getPropB().toLowerCase().compareTo(lhs.getPropB().toLowerCase());
            }
        case ASC:
            switch (fieldSort) {
                case NORMAL:
                    return lhs.getPropA().toLowerCase().compareTo(rhs.getPropA().toLowerCase());;
                case ASC:
                    return 0; // 0 used as placeholder
                default:
                    return 0; // 0 used as placeholder
            }
        default:
            switch (fieldSort) {
                case NORMAL:
                    return rhs.getPropA().toLowerCase().compareTo(lhs.getPropA().toLowerCase());
                case ASC:
                    return 0; // 0 used as placeholder
                default:
                    return 0; // 0 used as placeholder
            }
    }
}
```

**How can I sort with two different fields, each with their own order of sorting?**

Comment: Two comments. First, when ASC/DESC is specified for both fields, you will need to evaluate the comparison for one of the fields (whichever is "dominant"). If this is non-zero, then return that value.  Only if the first comparison is zero (i.e.  the first property was equal) _then_ you consider the comparison of the second field.  The second point, is that if you use `case ASC` and `case DESC` then `default` will fit more naturally with your settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little bit confused of your `Comparator`. It's not easy to understand what switch triggers what event.
However I'll describe the standard procedure.

You'll need a **priority order** over your fields you want to compare. In your example above, I assume it first must be sorted by `propA`, then by `propB`.
Then you first sort by `propA`. If it returns "*equals*" (**zero**), then you want to sort by the next field, `propB`, and so on.

Let me show you an example:

```
@Override
public int compare(final Field lhs, final Field rhs) {
    int firstCompareValue = lhs.getPropA().compareTo(rhs.getPropA());

    if (firstCompareValue == 0) {
        // lhs and rhs are equals in propA, use propB
        int secondCompareValue = lhs.getPropB().compareTo(rhs.getPropB());
        return secondCompareValue;
    } else {
        return firstCompareValue;
    }
}
```

Of course you can also do this iterative if you have multiple fields, as long as you have specified an order (e.g. by using an ordered list over your property fields).

Now you need to add your switches to this showcase :) I'll recommend doing a `PropertyComparator` for that.

```
public final class PropertyComparator extends Comparator<Comparable<?>> {
    private final boolean mUseDscOrder = false;

    public void setUseDscOrder(final boolean useDscOrder) {
            mUseDscOrder = useDscOrder;
    }

    public int compare(final Comparable<?> o1, final Comparable<?> o2) {
            if (!mUseDscOrder) {
                    return o1.compareTo(o2);
            } else {
                    // Reverses the logic, results in DscOrder
                    return o2.compareTo(o1)
            }
    }
}
```

And now use it in the above `Comparator`.

```
@Override
public int compare(final Field lhs, final Field rhs, final boolean firstUseDscOrder, final boolean secondUseDcsOrder) {
    PropertyComparator firstComparator = new PropertyComparator();
    firstComparator.setUseDscOrder(firstUseDscOrder);

    int firstCompareValue = firstComparator.compare(lhs.getPropA(), rhs.getPropA());

    if (firstCompareValue == 0) {
        // lhs and rhs are equals in propA, use propB

        PropertyComparator secondComparator = new PropertyComparator();
        secondComparator.setUseDscOrder(secondUseDscOrder);

        int secondCompareValue = secondComparator.compare(lhs.getPropB(), rhs.getPropB());
        return secondCompareValue;
    } else {
        return firstCompareValue;
    }
}
```

I've not tested it but I think you get the idea :)

Comment: I ended up forgetting to change some of the code when I pasted this, like the switch conditions. Anyway, I ended up modifying the top bit of your code and dropping it into where I was missing return values. Working like a charm now (lots of overhead, probably going to run in an async task). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create 1 `comparator` that sorts on the "first field". If the values of the first field are equal, sort on the "second field".

```
if(object1.f1.equals(object2.f1)){

 object1.f2.compareTo(object2.f2);

} else {

  object1.f1.compareTo(object2.f1); 

}
```